# Predeterminers do not normally co-occur

Tags: grammatical-number

Predeterminers do not normally co-occur:

```
    *all half my salary
```

I cannot get what this mean!

Comment: It's not grammatical English and doesn't mean anything: that's what the asterisk at the front signifies.

Comment: You see that leading asterisk, there? That means it's an erroneous, impossible, bogus construction. In other words, native speakers cannot get what that sentence means, either. In terms of what's being said about it, *why* it's bogus: well, you discovered that for yourself already. Because semantically it doesn't make sense. You can't make sense of it because words like *all* and *half* (predeterminers) do not pair up like that.

Comment: Thanks. So, what could we say instead of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [site](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/determin/xdetm3.htm) from which you appear to have taken this shows very clearly that a **predeterminer** is a determiner occupying a specific “slot” in a noun phrase—the first slot, before the **determiner** slot. It names three major types of predeterminer, and lists  typical examples of each:

1. “Multiplying” expressions — *twice, double, ten times*
2. Fractions: *half, one-third*
3. The words *all* and *both*

It then says that “Predeterminers do not normally co-occur”—that is, you do not usually find two predeterminers next to each other. And it gives an example:

> *all half my salary

Here *all* and *half* are both predeterminers, as listed previously; they sit next to each other in the noun phrase; and exactly as the site says, this co-occurrence is ungrammatical. That is the conventional significance in linguistic texts of an asterisk in front of an utterance.

It doesn’t mean ***anything*** in English; that’s the whole point. And since it doesn’t mean anything, it cannot be paraphrased.

We might ***guess*** what somebody writing this meant—perhaps something like “fully half my salary” or “no less than half my salary”—but without more context, that’s only a guess.